# MPMusicPlayerController not posting notifications?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, iphone

I"m trying to use the `MPMusicPlayerController` to play music, and I also want to receive the notification `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange`.  I set up my player and notification registration pretty much just like the sample (which works, BTW - it receives notifications correctly):

```
- (id) initWithPlaylist:(MPMediaPlaylist*)list {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        player = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
        [player retain];

        NSLog(@"setting up player");
        [plaayer setQueueWithItemCollection:list];
        [player setShuffleMode:MPMusicShuffleModeOff];
        [player setRepeatMode:MPMusicRepeatModeNone];

        NSLog(@"registering MPMusicPlayerController Notifications");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(handle_itemChanged:) 
                                                     name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handle_stateChanged:)
                                                     name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        NSLog(@"turning on player notifications");
        [player beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
    }
}
```

I get a whole lot of bupkis.  The methods `handle_itemChanged:` and `handle_stateChanged:` are just empty except for an `NSLog` statement to show they've been hit, and it never appears that they get hit.  The `NSLog` statements in `initWithPlaylist:` are printed to the log as expected.  The above is just a business object in my app.  It's not a view or view controller.

Any ideas?  The bizarre thing is that the `AddMusic` sample works just fine for me, and I can't tell that I"m doing anything differently with regard to the `MPMusicPlayerController` and its notifications.

**Update**:  I've added this line in my app delegate to see the full flood of notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:nil object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *n) { NSLog(@"notification: %@", n); }];
```

I see all kinds of notifications being printed to the console, but none from the media player controller.

Comment: aarrrgggh!  This is bonkers!  I still can't figure why the notifications aren't being posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the answer: the player has to be sent messages on the main thread.  It makes some sense in retrospect, but it was completely non-obvious until the moment it dawned on me.  I modified the bug I opened to be a bug on the documentation because I never did spot where they mentioned that the player must be operated on the main thread.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, but my notifications are being registered in the `viewDidLoad` method of a view controller. I'm able to receive notifications for `MPMediaLibraryDidChangeNotification` from `MPMediaLibrary` but cannot receive any for `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You should add another line above these lines:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handle_itemChanged:)
                                             name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

that is:

```
[myPlayer beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
```

it worked for me.