# How do I get information about the music being played using Nativescript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, nativescript

Is there such a possibility at all?

Comment: It should be possible. Since nativescript is just a framework, the definite answer to this should depend on how the developer do the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

As [you can access the full API of the underlying system (iOS/Android) from   NativeScript](http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/marshalling/Marshalling-Overview) you can make an API [request to iOS for the current music being played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157211/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-currently-played-track-while-the-iphone-is-connecte#comment20968223_14848511).

Side note: This is the big strength of NativeScript. Even if something isn't built into the framework you may still access it. Here's [an example of how to modify the iOS Navigation Bar](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/customizing-ios-navigation-bar-status-bar-nativescript/#hiding-the-back-button), by accessing the iOS APIs.